# Передача данных при клике Vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Всем привет,нужна помощь,как при клике на карточку слева,отображать данные этой карточки в окне справа(название,заемщик и т.д) Объясните пожалуйста) Вот код карточки.

```
<v-card
            tabindex="1"
            class="elevation-4 mb-3"
            v-for="ad in info"
            :key="ad.id">
              <v-flex xs4>
              </v-flex>
            <div class="table">
              <v-flex xs8>
                <v-card-text>
                  <h2> {{ad.car.make}} {{ad.car.model}}</h2>
                  <p></p>
                  <p><b>{{ad.car.licensePlate}} |  VIN: {{ad.car.vin}}<br> {{ad.client.clientName}}</b></p>
                  <p class="status-info"><b>{{ad.creditAgreementNumber}}</b> <br/> {{ad.creditAgreementStatus}}</p>
                </v-card-text>
                <v-card-actions>
                  <v-spacer></v-spacer>
                </v-card-actions>
              </v-flex>
            </div>
          </v-card>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Большого опыта в vue.js не имею, но, я так полагаю у вас имеется масив данных карточек, когда кликаете на одну из, нужно смотреть индекс активной карточки, и я бы на пример подтягивал те саме данные изходя из активного индекса

Comment: я данные получаю из API

Comment: А в каком формате прилетают данные вам?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю актуален ли ещё вопрос, но мало ли, данную команду v-on:click="func(($event, [arr.card, arr.id]))" вешаете на карточку на которую надо нажать, что бы передать данные 
arr - ваш массив, дальше принимаем входящие параметры в methods: {func: function(event) {console.log(event)}} в event все параметры из массива которые вы туда поместили, дальше работаете с ними по своему усмотрению